# How to search "people and group" list items in an entire site collection for a particular user and replace that user in powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-list

There are lots of ways a person could be displayed in a list using a "people and groups" field. I have a script that will find and update a user if they are being displayed in a list as "Name(with presence)". I do this by searching for the string in the item fields. However, if for instance the user is only being displayed as "ID", "first name", "last name", or so forth, then my script can't find them and it will not update them. I'm working in SP2016 environment.

How can I have my script actually find the user no matter how they are displayed in the list?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: So this is impossible??**

Comment: Without seeing your code, my initial question is: can you validate that all of the columns you are searching are ‘person’-typed columns?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289382/return-list-values-from-column-type-user-and-replace-that-user-if-they-exist-u/289383#289383). I think your question contains same concept of posted link above.